# when we select Exact button the value of nameMatchingValue should be 100, when i choose Partial, value come from select control how to solve this?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

the value of nameMatchingValue will come from either nameMatching Strategy(E button --> text field) or (P button --> select control), but always i'm getting `nameMatchingValue=100`.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="form-group ra">
     <label for="inputuid3" class="col-sm-12 control-label ">Matching Strategy</label>
     <form:radiobutton path="nameMatchingStrategy" value="E" id="exactRadiobtnId" class="form-control exact" required="true"/>
     <label for="exactRadiobtnId" class="control-label " >Exact</label>
     <form:radiobutton path="nameMatchingStrategy" value="P" id="partialRadiobtnId" class="form-control partial" required="true"/>
     <label for="partialRadiobtnId" class="control-label ">Partial</label>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputuid3" class="col-sm-12 control-label ">Matching Value</label>
     <form:input path="nameMatchingValue" id="exactMatchingNumberId" class="form-control exact_value" placeholder="Matching Value" value="100" readonly="true"/>
     <form:select path="nameMatchingValue" id="matchingNumberId" class="form-control no-margin partial_value">
         <form:option value="99">99</form:option>
         <form:option value="98">98</form:option>
         <form:option value="97">97</form:option>
         <form:option value="96">96</form:option>
         <form:option value="95">95</form:option>
         <form:option value="94">94</form:option>
         <form:option value="93">93</form:option>
         <form:option value="92">92</form:option>
         <form:option value="91">91</form:option>
         <form:option value="90">90</form:option>
         <form:option value="89">89</form:option>
         <form:option value="88">88</form:option>
         <form:option value="87">87</form:option>
         <form:option value="86">86</form:option>
         <form:option value="85">85</form:option>
         <form:option value="84">84</form:option>
         <form:option value="83">83</form:option>
         <form:option value="82">82</form:option>
         <form:option value="81">81</form:option>
         <form:option value="80">80</form:option>
       </form:select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Because you've given the same path value to input & select fields. While parsing HTML it will return the first match.

Comment: that is the requirement I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using javascript. You can create a hidden variable  `nameMatchingValue` as  `<form:hidden path = "nameMatchingValue" id="nameMatchingValue"/>`

You can then create 2 fields with different names as below.

```
    <input type="text" name="exactMatchingNumberId" value="100" readonly="true"/>
    <select name="matchingNumberId">
     ...
    </select>
```

You can then set the value of `nameMatchingValue` based on the value of `nameMatchingStrategy` while submitting the form as below.

```
    function submitForm(){
       var strategyValue = getStrategyValue();
       //set value based on strategy
       if(strategyValue == "E"){
   document.yourform.nameMatchingValue.value=document.yourform.exactMatchingNumberId.value;
       }else if(strategyValue == "P"){
                document.yourform.nameMatchingValue.value=document.yourform.matchingNumberId.value;
       }
       document.yourform.submit();
    }

     //get value from radio button
     function getStrategyValue(){
           var val;
           var strategyObj = document.yourform.nameMatchingStrategy;
          for (var i=0, len=strategyObj.length; i<len; i++) {
            if ( strategyObj[i].checked ) {
              val = strategyObj[i].value;
              break; 
            } 
        }
        return val;
    }
```